# query optimization, sql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Do you have any idea how to optimize this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    branch
WHERE
    wid IN (
        SELECT
            MAX(wid) AS wid
        FROM
            branch
        WHERE
            og = 'XXX'
        AND st = 'YYY'
        AND guide IN ('...')
        AND uid IN ('...')
        GROUP BY
            uid,
            guide
    )
AND stp = 1;

 CREATE TABLE `branch` (
 `wid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `branchid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `stp` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `st` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 `og` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 ...
 PRIMARY KEY (`wid`,`branchid`,`stp`),
 KEY `branch_guide_d` (`guide`,`d`),
 KEY `branch_st_c` (`st`,`c`),
 KEY `branch_st_m` (`st`,`m`),
 KEY `branch_uid_guide_wid` (`uid`,`guide`,`wid`),
)
```

Comment: Please add `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` queries.

Comment: And Avoid IN queries and use inner joins

Comment: You can use only required column name instead of SELECT "*".

Comment: For best results you should learn how to use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html). This will tell you what the query is doing and any areas where it's not using any indexes or have exponential joins. Searching for "How to use explain to optimize queries" gives lots of articles. To be proficient with writing queries learning EXPLAIN is undoubtably the best thing you could do.

Comment: Please try my answer and reply to me if ti works or not

Comment: Don't use `IN ( SELECT...)`, it often does not perform well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use the following query

```
SELECT
        MAX(wid) AS wid into #Temp 
    FROM
        branch
    WHERE
        og = 'XXX'
    AND st = 'YYY'
    AND guide IN ('...')
    AND uid IN ('...')
    GROUP BY
        uid,
        guide
```

Then Create an Index

```
Create Clustered Index Temp On  #Temp(wid)
```

Now Use Join

```
Select b.* 
from branch b 
join #Temp t on t.wid=b.wid where st = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join instead of 'IN'

```
SELECT branch.*
FROM branch
INNER JOIN
(
        SELECT MAX(wid) AS wid
        FROM branch
        WHERE og = 'XXX'
        AND st = 'YYY'
        AND guide IN ('...')
        AND uid IN ('...')
        GROUP BY uid, guide
)tb 
ON tb.wid = branch.wid
AND st = 1;
```

Comment: the same performance like original query. I will try to chnge it AND uid IN ('...')  - to join

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM branch b
WHERE wid IN (SELECT MAX(wid) AS wid
              FROM branch b2
              WHERE og = 'XXX' AND st = 'YYY' AND guide IN ('...') AND
                    uid IN ('...')
              GROUP BY uid, guide
             ) AND
     stp = 1;
```

If `MAX(wid)` is unique, then I would write this as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM branch b JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(wid) AS wid
      FROM branch b2
      WHERE og = 'XXX' AND st = 'YYY' AND guide IN ('...') AND
            uid IN ('...')
      GROUP BY uid, guide
     ) bb
     ON b.wid = bb.wid
WHERE b.stp = 1;
```

Then indexes.  The following come to mind:  `branch(stp, wid)` and `branch(og, stp, guid, uid, wid)`.  Depending on which is  more selective, you might really want:  `branch(og, stp, uid, guid, wid)`.